# Cat 6 cable unable to reach gigabit speeds?

Tags: networking

I have made my own cat 6 cable (run length 30m) but I cant seem to get gigabit speeds with it (my old cable can but its too short). Its stuck at 100mbps now. I suspect im doing something wrong... I have tried the following:

1) Replacing both heads

2) cutting another length of cable and putting two heads on

[image: Head 1 Front]
[image: Head 1 Back]
[image: Head 1 Top]
[image: Head 2 Front]
[image: Head 2 Back]

Comment: Does the working cable have a shielded connector, i.e. with metal around? Do the leads all have a connection to the pins on both sides (try a multimeter or test lamp)?

Comment: No, my working gigabit cable does not have a shielded connector.

Comment: Can you verify you have 10/100/1000 LAN ports on all your devices (routers, PCs, switches, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, I have a perfectly fine gigabit connection now, but when using this cable it drops to 10/100. I see 1.0Gbps in the Network and Sharing Center > Ethernet Status window with my old cable, and 100Mbps with the new one

Comment: @aCuria Do you have a multimeter with continuity testing you can run over each wire to make sure there are no broken pairs, as TJJ suggested? If any one wire is not making a connection it'll fall back to 100Mbps, as all 8 wires are required for gigabit. I realise you tried cutting a new cable, but if you can be certain it'll eliminate one other potential cause.

Comment: Are those cable connectors cat6, are any components (wall jacks etc) not cat6?  We had a contractor that cut corners etc... Even tho the wire was cat6 we couldn't get speed because of the junky wall plates and connectors.

Comment: @ Tyson, this is just a cable running from router <--> pc, theres nothing in between like a wall jack

Comment: Do you have cat6 specific connectors? Or did you just buy RJ45 ends and there not cat6 connectors

Comment: Where did you get the cable? There are plenty of ebay sellers that will sell junk aluminium UTP as CAT6 that really isnt.

Comment: exactly @Linef4ult

Comment: @aCuria did you find out?  I have a similar issue.

Comment: @HCSF In the end i think it boils down to the quality of the cable (shielding) and if theres any inteferance from other wiring running in parallel to your ethernet cable. My working theory is that since the cost of (my) labor is worth so much more than the cable, the best approach for small amounts of cable would be to only do projects with the best cables possible (Today this would be cat-8 cables). If sourced correctly, at least for me the cost difference between quality cat 6 and cat 7a or cat8 cables is marginal vs the cost of labor.

Comment: @HCSF In the end the cable listed in the OP worked fine when tested when laid out in a straight line on its own, but once installed into the trunking reaching gigabit speeds was intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use STP (shielded twisted pair) or FTP (foiled ..) or even SFTP (shielded + foiled ..) cat.6 cable instead of UTP (unshielded twisted pair). UTP is usually used over short distances only!
And if you are using a cable with shielding, also use shielded connectors.

Comment: How short is short? the run is only 20-30m...

Comment: @aCuria: Short means 0.5 to 3m. Remember the cable limit of 100m on Ethernet, so 20m is definitely not short anymore.

Comment: 20 meters shouldn't cause a degradation down to 100Mbps with UTP. Can you cite a source for that? I'm sure I've used lengths above this (Under 100m of course) previously and not had a problem.

Comment: Depends on what sources of electric noise are next to the cable. Obviously there are some, which in this case are too many. But I just had the idea for another possible cause: GBE needs all 4 pairs, FE uses only 2 (1-2, 3-6). So, if one of 4, 5, 7, 8 is faulty, you don't get GBE speed.

Comment: The cable is just running free on the floor, away from any electrical cables...